# page number in vf page

Tags: visualforce, navigation, pagination, number

hi all i need pagination in vf page. i've tried increase and reduce `currentPage` number in navigation button but it didn't work. here my code:

controller:

```
public PageReference Next() {
    currentPageNumber += 1;
    return null;
}
```

and vf page:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" value="Next"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!currentPageNumber}" />
<apex:outputText value=" / " />
<apex:outputText value="{!pageNumber}" />
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i calculated `currentpagenumber` in controller constructor method, not in navigation button.
here is my code:

controller:

```
currentPageNumber = pageNumber - ((totalRecords - offSetSize) / queryLimit);
```

and it works!